# Return result from function from another python file

Tags: python, google-api

I'm trying to pull data from gsheets into python so I can run an algorithm but I can't seem to make it work. The API with Google Sheets is working, it just seems that it's running the pull but not storing the data. When I call the function main() (which pulls the data from google sheets) it just does nothing.

This below is the data pull with the main() function.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import numpy as np

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']

# The ID and range of a sample spreadsheet.
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = '12pXiwMxrRD6fgPmdzopn0JNNpMCFKEtJ0rCJmCSdhCo'
SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME = 'FW!A1:DD10000'

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Sheets API.
    Prints values from a sample spreadsheet.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Sheets API
    sheet = service.spreadsheets()
    result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME, majorDimension='ROWS').execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])
"""
    if not values:
        print('No data found.')
    else:
        print('Name, Major:')
        for row in values:
            # Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
            print('%s, %s' % (row[0], row[4]))
"""
main()
```

And this is first part of the file in which I'm trying to call the function main() from the other file.

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import gsheets_LH

m1 = gsheets_LH.main()

print(m1)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `main()` does not return anything, so it implicitly returns `None`. You need to change it, if you want to return something. Also note, that when you import your module, main will be executed once, because you call it at the end of the module.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the function `main()` returns something, what it's supposed to. Currently it returns nothing.

Also, the `main()` at the last line where you call the function should only be put inside the following context so it doesn't run every time you call main() from the outside (in addition to the call you make, thus making two calls.)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks Omri. May be a stupid question, but I was under the impression that the 'values' in main() was storing the result. Any suggestion as to how I can store the range it's reading as a variable or something I can use or refer to somewhere else?

Comment: Hey, I missed your comment. Sorry about that. If it is still relevant, can you explain more what you mean? I'm not sure I understand.